# Simular busca de dados APP (Android) em PHP/Python

Tags: php, android, libcurl

Gostaria de dicas e caminhos de como posso simular a busca de dados de um APP (Android) em PHP ou Python.

Achei interessante este exemplo https://github.com/victor-torres/sinesp-client, onde o APP Sinesp-Cidadão é simulado em Python.

Como posso debugar o APP para identificar URLS, Tokens, Passwords, Headers, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Esse app Sinesp-Cidadão não está sendo simulado, esse código é apenas um facilitador para fazer requisições para a API de verdade do app em python...

Caso você queira fazer algo parecido com algum outro app, você tem que estudar um pouco sobre HTTP Requests, XMLHttpRequests e entender a diferença de uma API Rest e Soap. Dentro disso existem os tokens, login e etc, mas isso é algo mais específico da aplicação e cada uma tem a sua forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Para que eu possa localizar os tokens, logins e etc do APP, como posso fazer o debug para conseguir essas informações, existe alguma ferramenta específica para isso?

Comment: Existem API's que são abertas e não exigem autenticação, o que é o caso desse app. Ele apenas seta o endereço da api e o device que ele está usando: https://github.com/victor-torres/sinesp-client/blob/master/src/sinesp_client/body.xml

Comment: Se respondeu sua pergunta, marque la como resolvido... Vlw

Comment: Minha dúvida é como posso obter o endereço da API e outros dados. Pelo que parece o desenvolvedor do APP não disponibiliza isso de forma livre.

Comment: Isso depende da API no caso desse projeto ele acessa uma api do governo  e cada api tem sua documentação definindo quais endereços vão retornar determinadas informações... Como eu disse você precisa dar uma olhada como funciona API's e Webservices

Comment: E ae resolveu sua dúvida ?

Answer (score 0):

Há várias maneiras de debugar requisições, ou até mesmo código de apks.

Para monitoramento das requisições enviadas e recebidas através do APK a maneira mais simples de debugar é através de outros APKs que realizam esse monitoramento. Você pode usar por exemplo o Packet Capture, ou Shark Native, ou derivados.
Há também a possibilidade de inspecionar as requisições através do adb logcat.

Porém, a forma mais eficiente, e que para esse caso é a que faz mais sentido, você precisa ler e entender o codigo fonte do APK para tratar as requisições. Já que não é um simples POST. Tu vais precisar além de formatar um SOAP, gerar o Token de acordo como a aplicação pede para que esse SOAP seja validado.
Para isso, você pode baixar o APK do sinesp-cidadao através de um site externo, por exemplo, apk pure. E Utilizar uma ferramenta como o dex2jar para realizar a engenharia reversa gerando um .jar e para visualizar o conteúdo você pode usar uma ferramenta como o JD-GUI, por exemplo, para decompilar o jar.